# Postgresql Exception Logging

Tags: postgresql, exception, plpgsql

Need help in taking care of the below requirement.

We need to take care of exceptions that could come in a pl sql block and log certain values from the select statement into a tailor made table - audit_log.
For example:

audit_log table structure:
col1, stored_procedure_name, error_code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_TEMP()
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
declare


begin
    /* loop through the data in table_a */ 
    for sq in (select a.column1,a.column2..a.columnN from table_a a  )

     
    loop
        /*Do some operations (not shown here) and select data from table_b */
        (                                                                                                                                                  
        select col1, col2, col3 
        from table_b b where 
        b.col1=sq.column1 )                                                                                                                                                  
        /*insert into table_c*/
        insert into table_c
        values(sq.column1,sq.column2,b.col2,b.col3);
        
    end loop;


   EXCEPTION:
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
    /* Log the failure information to audit_log table */
    insert into audit_log
    values(column1, 'SP_TEMP',SQLERRM)
    
    
end

$procedure$
;
```

Is it possible to do this? How to pass column1 value to the exception?

We were not able to pass the column1 value to the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a nested (inner block) inside the cursor loop. Then put your `exception` processing inside this block.

```
    create or replace procedure sp_temp()
     language plpgsql
    as $$
    declare
    begin
        /* loop through the data in table_a */ 
        for sq in (select a.column1,a.column2..a.columnn from table_a a  )
        loop
            
           begin  -- inner block to allow processing the exception
              /*do some operations (not shown here) and select data from table_b */
              (                                                                                                                                                  
              select col1, col2, col3 
              from table_b b where 
              b.col1=sq.column1 )                                                                                                                                                  
              /*insert into table_c*/
              insert into table_c
              values(sq.column1,sq.column2,b.col2,b.col3);
           exception
               when others then
                /* log the failure information to audit_log table */
                insert into audit_log
                values(sq.column1, 'sp_temp',sqlerrm);
    
            end; -- inner block   
        end loop;   
    end;
    $$;
```

NOTE: be careful of `when others` as the only predicate in the exception block. There are likely some conditions you want to handle and continue and others abort processing. Use `when others` only as the last resort.

Comment: It cannot to work - `RAISE` does rollback of the insert to audit_log table

Comment: You are correct. Too much Oracle Autonomous Transaction this last month, I guess. Answer updated. Thanks.

Comment: @Belayer Thanks for the response. This worked for our need. We didnt use raise further.